# Obstruction theory and maps from a 3-manifold to the sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, obstruction-theory

Let $Y$ be a $3$-manifold. Two maps $f,g \colon Y \rightarrow S^2$ are *homologous* if they are homotopic in the complement of a $3$-ball in $Y$.

At the beginning of Section 2.6 of Ozsváth and Szabó's first paper (arXiv:math/0101206v4), the authors identify the set of homology classes of maps $Y \rightarrow S^2$ with $H^2(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ in the following way: fixing a generator $\mu \in H^2(S^2;\mathbb{Z})$, the map sends the class of $f \colon Y \rightarrow S^2$ to the pull-back $f^*\mu$.

I do not see why this is a bijection. I understand that it follows from "elementary obstruction theory", but I do not know enough obstruction theory to see how. Could anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $S^2$ is the 3-skeleton of $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ and $[X,\mathbb{C}P^\infty]\cong H^2X$ for any complex $X$. Thus $[X,S^2]\cong H^2X$ for any 2-complex $X$. These statements are usually derived from "elementary obstruction theory".

If we assume that the 3-manifold $Y$ is orientable, then we can equip it with a CW structure with a unique 3-cell, and then being homologous is the statement that two maps are homotopic on the 2-skeleton (we can without loss of generality remove the 3-ball from the interior of the top cell). Of course the above applies and identifies the homotopy classes of maps $Y_2\rightarrow S^2$ with $H^2(Y_2)\cong H^2(Y)$.

Comment: Thank you! It is much clearer now.

Comment: Is the assumption that $Y$ is orientable necessary to conclude that it has a CW structure with a unique $3$-cell?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I would suggest not (consider $S^1\times\mathbb{R}P^2$). I don't know the full story off the top of my head, tho.

Comment: Doesn't that example have such a CW decomposition?  If one takes a CW structure on $S^1$ with one $1$-cell, and a CW structure on $\mathbb{R}P^2$ with one $2$-cell, then the product CW structure has a unique $3$-cell, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Just the double negative ;). The example was to show that the orientability assumption is *not* necessary.

Comment: What we do lose in the nonorientable case is the isomorphism $H^2(Y_2)\cong H^2(Y)$.

Comment: Oh!  You answered what I actually asked instead of what I meant to ask - sorry about that.  Real question:  are there closed connected manifolds which don't admit a CW structure having a unique top dimensional cell?  (Anyway, I'm off to bed now before I make other dumb errors!)